# How to show QR code using Google Charts in Crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, qr-code

Currently I managed to show inside Crystal report QR code using Google Charts and dynamically change path of picture but the generated QR code is wrong. I need to show URL with GET methode (3 params) and link is showing only 1st param.

test URL which needs to be opened via QR code (formula "link")

```
"http://test.com/getData?param1=aaa&param2=bbb"
```

formula for QR code and dynamically changing picture (it's http because Crystal Reports doesn't support https)

```
"http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=" + {@link}
```

Those two combined form a string

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http://test.com/getData?param1=aaa&param2=bbb
```

QR code - wrong one (missing param 2)

[image: wrong qr]

If I change my link to (url encoding & into %26)

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http://test.com/getData?param1=aaa%26param2=bbb
```

then I get with browser good QR code but in Crystal reports still wrong one (missing param 2)

QR code - good in browser but not showing the same in Crystal

[image: good qr]

I suspect that something is wrong with URL encoding in Crystal or different than browser encoding. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of hours trying encoding/decoding data I accidently figure out that it wasn't problem in data or URL. Only thing I had to do is check "use original URL" in picture properties. After that generated QR code was good and problem solved. Hope it helps someone and saves lots of hours.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is due to http limitation, you can generate the QR barcode image locally using a Crystal Reports UFL. You can create your own or at least one of the 3rd-party UFLs listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) provides such a function.

Comment: I forgot to mention it that open source solutions is what I am looking for